# Чтение\запись неразмеченной памяти MassStorage

Tags: usb, драйвер, системное-программирование

Передо мной стоит задача сделать на MassStorage скрытый раздел. "Скрытость" раздела подразумевает, что работать с ним можно только из моего ПО, а для ОС данный раздел существовать не должен.

MassStorage при этом также должен иметь один обычный раздел. 
В качестве решения я хочу попробовать следующее: Традиционным способом создать обычный раздел. После обычного раздела с известным  только моему ПО смещением разместить таблицу разделов, описывающую мой скрытый раздел.

Соответственно, при работе моё ПО должно считывать находить спрятанную таблицу разделов, из нее получать информацию о скрытом разделе и далее работать как с обычным разделом.

Суть вопроса в поиске инструментов реализации. Писать с нуля драйвер MassStorage как-то не хочется. Возможно, существует инструмент или библиотека для работы с не размеченной памятью MassStorage?

Буду благодарен за ссылку на opensource msd драйвер для Windows, а также за любые советы по решению описанной задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Написал утилиту для работы с не размеченной памятью. Мои нужды закрыла) 
https://github.com/Rexarrior/HiddenMassStorageUtility